# Is there an online critique community for stories written in german?

Tags: language, criticism, community

I am writing fiction in german. I am looking for a place to share my work, where I can get constructive criticism.

The site should provide some mechanism that encouraged constructive feedback and some kind of voting mechanism for published stories. I found [critters](http://www.critters.org), which would be what I'm looking for. Except it's english only.

Is there a functioning online critique community for german content?

Answer (score 1):

All German language forums for writers as well as most forums for fans and writers of specific literary genres have subforums where you can post your own work and receive critique. Use any search engine and search for either "Schriftsteller Forum" or "[your genre] Forum" (e.g. "Fantasy Forum").

A few examples:

- http://www.dsfo.de/
- http://www.schreibwerkstatt.de/
- http://autorenforum.montsegur.de/
- http://forum.42erautoren.de/
- http://www.bod.de/autorenpool/
- http://www.literaturforum.net/

Comment: Thanks. Do you have experience with any of these? Do they have some policy or mechanism that encourages constructive feedback like on critters?

Comment: I have used many of these forums, but never to receieve criticism, so while I know that those that I used are active and helpful, I cannot say anything about the quality or rules of giving and getting criticism. I'd just read around a bit, see what kind of stories get posted, what kind of feedback they get, and then try those that you find attractive. Due to less German than English speakers, German language communities are generally smaller than those in English, and you should not expect the same level of activity. Otherwise they are just as good/bad.

Answer (score 0):

I found the site wortkrieger.de (formerly kurzgeschichten.de) myself.

But I don't know if it is functioning well and I didn't find information about how this site works in the FAQ section.

If anyone has experience with this site please add a comment.

Comment: Register, log in, participate. It works like any other forum.

Comment: Thank you. So no special mechanism like "write a feedback to get a feedback" or a voting system for stories? Just a forum where you post your story and every participiant who wants to posts his feedback.

Comment: I'm not a member, I just looked at the forum, read around a bit and read the rules for registering, and it all looks like any other forum to me. I don't see any signs of a voting system or that you must write feedback to get feedback. Probably other members will note if you only "take" but never "give", but a duty to "be social" does not appear to be implemented in the software. Though maybe it will only become apparent after you register.